# Stacking dynamically growing divs on each other without spaces between them

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I want to stack divs one after other without any space in between them but i've failed to do this. I've tried this on table and tried all methods to remove spacing between rows of a table but I failed. Now I am trying to implement the same with divs and I am unable to achieve the desired output. Below is my code.

```
    @model IEnumerable<Fast_Tally_Accounter.Models.CPVBase>
<p style="background-image:url('../../viewData/vcr_header.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; border:0">
</p>
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var v in Model)
    {
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:120px;background-image:url('../../viewData/vcr_row.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <p style="padding-top:inherit;">@v.headText</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p style="padding-top:inherit; margin-left:5px;">@v.amount</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    }
}
<div class="row" style="margin-left:120px;margin-top:-30px;background-image:url('../../viewData/vcr_total_footer.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p style="margin-left:450px;">@ViewBag.total</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is what the above code looks like on a browser
[click here to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBVSS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It its Bootstrap then the nesting of elements is incorrect. Class "col" must be immediate child of "row". Also the sum of sizes of col must be 12 in one row. You have 6 + 4 i.e. 10. Make it col-lg-8 and col-lg-4 to fill the entire row.

Try changing this -

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p style="padding-top:inherit;">@v.headText</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p style="padding-top:inherit; margin-left:5px;">@v.amount</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

to this - (Basically, remove the col-lg-12 div and the corresponding closing div)

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <p>@v.headText</p>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <p>@v.amount</p>
</div>
```